# How can I improve this React component with correct lifecycle usage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I am trying to make a list item toggle on and off. So I capture the click event, send a request to my endpoint with `PATCH` method, get the new value returned from the backend and update the state of the component based on that value. And it works perfectly. But I have the feeling that I might have to use `useEffect` here in some way. But I can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export function ListItem({ id, content, checked }) {
    const token = useSelector(state => state.auth.token);

    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(checked);

    const makeRequest = async () => {
        const uri = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/listitems/${id}/`;

        const h = new Headers();
        h.append('Authorization', `Token ${token}`);
        h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        const req = new Request(uri, {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: h,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                checked: !isChecked
            }),
            mode: 'cors'
        })

        const response = await fetch(req);
        const json = await response.json();
        
        const result = json.checked;

        return result;
    }

    const handleClick = async (e) => {
        // request the endpoint to check/uncheck the item
        const result = await makeRequest();

        // add/remove the strikethrough class to/from the content
        setIsChecked(result);
    }

    return (
        <>
        <label>
            <input onChange={handleClick} type="checkbox" name="list-items" checked={isChecked}/>
            {isChecked ? <s children={content} /> : content}
        </label> <br/>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: It looks reasonable, though I'd suggest preventing multiple checkbox changes from triggering multiple requests

Comment: @CertainPerformance May you direct me to a resource where I might read a bit more about how I can achieve that? I'm trying to build a collaborative list, e.g. Google Keep allows multiple users to work on and build a list. So it's important that the database gets updated once someone checks off a list item.

Comment: Well you probably want to at least disable the checkbox while the request is in-flight.

Comment: Not sure if it's even needed or not, actually. If `makeRequest` takes 10 seconds, are you able to trigger multiple `handleClick`s before the 10 seconds are up? If not, there's nothing to worry about. If so, fix it by calling `e.preventDefault` inside the handler, or something similar.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Is `preventDefault()` useful for checkbox toggles? I thought they only prevent form submission.

Comment: Outside React, it'd prevent the click from toggling the checkbox.